# To prove norm on adjoint Banach space?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, adjoint-operators

Case:

[image]

which reminds me a lot about **Bourbaki–Alaoglu theorem** i.e. a unit case on a ball because of the last inequality and something with adjoint Hahn-Banach.

### My proposal by thinking the case on a ball [depreciated]

In the unit ball $D(x) = \{ u : \|u \| \leq 1 \}$ is not a compact set. 
    Consider any family of subspaces $E_{1} \subset E_{2} \subset ... \subset E_{n} \subset ...$ where $\text{dim } E_{n} = n$. 
    They are closed subspaces (since they are of finite dimension). 
    By Lemma of 5.2.1 of Eidelman et al, there exists a sequence $u_{i} \in E_{i}$ with $\| u_{i} \| = 1$ such that $\text{dist}(y_{i}, E_{i-1}) \geq 1/2$. 
    Then, for any $i \neq j$, $\| y_{i} - y_{j} \| \geq 1/2$. 
    Obviously, $\{ y_{i} \}$ is not a Cauchy sequence  and there is no Cauchy subsequence of it. $\square$

Sources

- Functional Analysis An Introduction by Eidelman, Corollary 5.2.2 and lemma 5.2.1

Comments

- To take a Cauchy sequence in Hahn-Banach here does not feel good because this variant of Hahn-Banach may be some complex version of it. I think this can be proved without considering any sequences.
- Eigenvalues come to my mind also by the statement and the Identity operator: $I : X \mapsto X$ that is not compact, like is not the case here.

### My proposal #2 after the first [hint](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1446469/17474)

Consider $\| \varphi \| < 1$ of the equation.
There exists $\varphi \in X'$ such that $\varphi = Span(u,X')$ for all $u \in X'$. 
Then, $\varphi(u) < 1$ because $\| \varphi \| < 1$. If $\varphi(u) > 1$, then $\| \varphi(u) \| > 1$, which is a contradiction to the initial assumption. 
Then, $\| \varphi \| < 1$ of the equation. $\square$

Consider $\| \varphi \| = 1$ of the equation. 
There exists $\varphi \in X'$ such that $\varphi = Span(u,X')$ for all $u \in X'$. 
Then, $\varphi(u) = 1$ because $\| \varphi \| = 1$. If $\varphi(u) \neq 1$, then $\| \varphi \| \neq 1$, so a contradiction to the initial assumption. 
Then, $\| u \| = 1$ so $\varphi(u) = \| u \|$. $\square$

Then, 
\begin{equation*}
\| u \| = \sup\{ \| \langle u, \varphi \rangle \| : \varphi \in X', \| \varphi \| \leq 1 \}. \, \square 
\end{equation*}

Comments

- I used the proof of contradiction to show the both sides. Is there any sense in my proof?

---

How can you prove the rigorously the case about the norm on Banach space?

Answer (score 2):

*some hints*:

First step: prove the "$\geq$" part of the equality 
$\|u\| = \sup \{ | \varphi(u) |: \varphi \in X', \|\varphi\| \leq 1 \}$. For this you only need to show that $\|u\| \geq \varphi(u)$ if $\varphi$ has the conditions mentioned.

Second step: show that there is a $\varphi \in X'$ with $ \varphi(u) = \| u \|$ using Hahn-Banach (start by defining $\varphi$ on $\mathrm{span} \, u$). Hahn-Banach also tells you that $\| \varphi \| \leq 1$. This shows you that the equality can be achieved.

Comment: Do you mean that the first step is to consider $\| \varphi \| < 1$ and the second step to consider $\| \varphi \| = 0$?

Comment: I added my proposal for the proof in the body of the question. What do you think about it?

Comment: @Masi i think you misunderstood. the equation i meant was your original equation/equality. i added something to my description for "First step".

Comment: @Masi also, i do not know what $Span ( u,X'
)$ means

Comment: *Span(u,X')* is all elements *u* in *X'*.